# Transition Data Animation after array.shift()

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

When using d3 or nvd3, I'm able to change data to the chart using something like the following:

```
  d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .datum(someDataArr)
      .call(chart);
```

Pushing an item onto the end of the someDataArr works as expected - a new item appears in the graph.  However, if I shift the first item off and push a new item to the end, d3 (understandably) transitions each data point according to its index.

In the case of a scatterplot, for example, this is undesirable.  I would prefer to remove the first item of the array but keep the plot points associated with their prior array index position.

Does anyone know how to keep the association between array[index] and chart points while also removing items from the beginning of the array?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What it boils down to is that you need to supply a key function to D3's `.data()` join. I'm assuming that you're using NVD3 -- for that, you'll have to modify the source or use plain D3.

Comment: You need to give a key function to use when doing the actual datajoin.  [This tutorial describes using keys with regular d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/); however, there is no "key function" option currently implemented in NVD3.  You could create an issue suggesting they implement it...